# Paso de parametros a interface

Tags: java, kotlin

Como puedo pasar la variable num_jor a la interface en el metodo getData?

```
class FragActual : Fragment() {

    var dataList = ArrayList<ActModel>()
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actual_list, container, false)
        return view
    }


    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val progressBar: ProgressBar = this.progressBar1

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.adapter= ActAdapter(dataList,activity!!)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context!!,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

        Thread(Runnable {
            activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            try {
                var i = 0
                while(i < Int.MAX_VALUE){
                    i++
                }
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }).start()

        val mutableList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(
            "1/6/2019", "8/6/2019", "16/6/2019", "24/6/2019", "1/7/2019",  "8/7/2019", "15/7/2019",  "30/7/2019", "15/8/2019", "30/8/2019",
            "1/9/2019", "8/9/2019", "16/9/2019", "24/9/2019", "1/10/2019",  "8/10/2019", "15/10/2019",  "30/10/2019", "15/11/2019", "30/11/2019",
            "1/12/2019", "8/12/2019", "16/12/2019", "24/12/2019", "1/7/2020",  "8/7/2020", "15/7/2020",  "30/7/2020", "15/8/2019", "30/6/2019")

        for ((indice, item) in mutableList.withIndex()) {
            val indice = indice+1

            val date = Calendar.getInstance()

            val dateformatter = SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy")
            val fechaInicial = (dateformatter.format(date.time))

            val date2 = Calendar.getInstance()
            date2.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)

            val dateformatter1 = SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy")
            val fechaFinal = (dateformatter1.format(date2.time))

            if (item == fechaInicial){

                val num_jor = indice
            }
        }
        getData()
    }

    private fun getData() {
        val call: Call<List<ActModel>> = Api000.getClient.getActJuvenil(num_jor)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ActModel>> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ActModel>>?, response: Response<List<ActModel>>?) {
                dataList.addAll(response!!.body()!!)
                recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ActModel>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

y aqui la ApiInterface

```
interface ApiInterface {

fun getActJuvenil(
        @Query("cmp") cmp: String,
        @Query("jor") jornada: String,
        @Query("tmp") temporada: String,
        @Query("mod") mod: String

    ): Call<List<ActModel>>

}
```

Comment: Podes publicar la interfaz ? no esta claro lo que preguntas, por que se podria pasar por parametro de getData() el valor num_jor , o hacer un metodo para setear ese valor en al interfaz, o pasarlo por parametro en el callback de la interfaz

Comment: Me basta con la jornada, lo demas esta claro. Post 1 editado

Comment: agrega el parametro num_jor y su tipo luego de mod: String en tu interfaz , luego cuando la llames con getactJuvenil te va a pedir pasarlo, y en el metodo de getData() pasas el num_jor

Comment: Lo que no se es como pasar el num_jor al getData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar el `num_jor` al `getdata()` solo modificas el metodo `getData()`

```
private fun getData(num_jor:Int) {
        val call: Call<List<ActModel>> = Api000.getClient.getActJuvenil(num_jor)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ActModel>> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ActModel>>?, response: Response<List<ActModel>>?) {
                dataList.addAll(response!!.body()!!)
                recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ActModel>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            }
        })
    }
```

y luego lo pasas donde lo necesites

```
getData(num_jor)
```

Comment: en getData(num_jor) num_jor se me queda en rojo, eso es lo que no entiendo

Comment: es por que el val num_jor esta declarado adentro del if, declaralo global como var num_jor: Int = -1 y luego lo usas adentro del if como num_jor = indice, lo declaro como -1 por que como no existe ese numero en el array, te va a dar una excepcion si lo usas mal (IndexOutOfBounds), asi te vas a dar cuenta que el problema viene de ahi , si lo declaras como 0 vas a tomar siempre el primer elemento aunque num_jor no este andando

Comment: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException - en la linea  - dataList.addAll(response!!.body()!!)

Comment: datalist es null por que nunca lo inicializaste, reemplaza `var dataList = ArrayList<ActModel>()` por `var dataList = arrayListOf<ActModel>()`